# Datatables issue using fixedColumns with Bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, datatables-1.10, bootstrap-tabs

I have a page with two bootstrap tabs, each tab contains one datatable. The below behavior started occurring only after I integrated fixedColumns into both datatables.

On page load the first table is displayed correctly and fixedColumns works correctly. When I click on the tab for table 2 then the table is displayed, but the page content which should be below the table is displayed on top of the table, and fixedColumns does not work.

---

**Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2:**

[image]

---

[Link to the snippet](http://live.datatables.net/zogicuvi/3/edit), though I am having a difficult time getting it to render anything.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
dataRetrievalpromise()
    .then(function (result) {
        generateTabsPromise(result)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                createTableHTMLPromise(result)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        createTableColumnsAndDataPromise(result);
                    });
            });
    });

//Below works only when debugging/using breakpoints
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    //$('.dTable:visible').each(function (e) {

    //    $(this).DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();

    //});
    $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true })
    .columns.adjust()
    .fixedColumns().relayout()
    .responsive.recalc();
    //.fixedHeader.adjust();
    //.columns.adjust().redraw()
});
});


var generateTabsPromise = function (trainerJson) {
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var result = {};
    var tabInfo = [];
    var allMonthsFromJson = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(trainerJson);
    var tabHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allMonthsFromJson.length; i++) {
        tabInfo.push(allMonthsFromJson[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tabInfo.length; i++) {
        //Make first tab active
        if (i == 0) {
            tabHTML += '<li class="active"><a href="' + '#tab-' + tabInfo[i] + '" data-toggle="tab"> ' + tabInfo[i] + '</a></li>';
        }
        else {
            tabHTML += '<li><a href="' + '#tab-' + tabInfo[i] + '" data-toggle="tab"> ' + tabInfo[i] + '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    $(".nav-tabs").html(tabHTML);
    result = { firstTab: tabInfo[0], jsonData: trainerJson, allMonthsInJson: allMonthsFromJson };
    resolve(result);
});
return promise;
};


function createTableHTMLPromise(generateTabsResult) {
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var tableHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < generateTabsResult.allMonthsInJson.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            tableHTML += '<div class="tab-pane active" id="' + 'tab-' + generateTabsResult.allMonthsInJson[i] + '">';
            tableHTML += '<table class="table dTable" id="' + 'table-' + generateTabsResult.allMonthsInJson[i] + '" cellspacing="0" width="100%">' + '</table>';
            tableHTML += '</div>';
        }
        else {
            tableHTML += '<div class="tab-pane" id="' + 'tab-' + generateTabsResult.allMonthsInJson[i] + '">';
            tableHTML += '<table class="table dTable" id="' + 'table-' + generateTabsResult.allMonthsInJson[i] + '" cellspacing="0" width="100%">' + '</table>';
            tableHTML += '</div>';
        }
    }
    $(".tab-content").html(tableHTML);
    result = { allMonthsInJson: generateTabsResult.allMonthsInJson, jsonData: generateTabsResult.jsonData };
    resolve(result);
});
return promise;
}


function createTableColumnsAndDataPromise(createTableHTMLResult) {
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var result = {};
    var columnResult = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < createTableHTMLResult.allMonthsInJson.length; i++) {

        var month = createTableHTMLResult.jsonData[createTableHTMLResult.allMonthsInJson[i]].metaData.month;
        var numDays = createTableHTMLResult.jsonData[createTableHTMLResult.allMonthsInJson[i]].metaData.numDays;
        var year = createTableHTMLResult.jsonData[createTableHTMLResult.allMonthsInJson[i]].metaData.year;
        var tabName = createTableHTMLResult.allMonthsInJson[i];

        columnResult.push({ "data": "managerName", title: "managerName", "name": "managerName", "defaultContent": "" });
        columnResult.push({ "data": "employeeName", title: "employeeName", "name": "employeeName", "defaultContent": "" });

        for (var j = 0; j < numDays; j++) {
            if (j + 1 < 10) {
                columnResult.push({ "data": month + "-0" + String(j + 1) + "-" + year, title: month + "-" + String(j + 1) + "-" + year, "name": month + "-" + String(j + 1) + "-" + year, "defaultContent": "" });
            }
            else {
                columnResult.push({ "data": month + "-" + String(j + 1) + "-" + year, title: month + "-" + String(j + 1) + "-" + year, "name": month + "-" + String(j + 1) + "-" + year, "defaultContent": "" });
            }
        }
        initiateTable(columnResult, createTableHTMLResult.jsonData[tabName].data, tabName);
        columnResult = [];
        tabName = "";
    }
    resolve(result);
});
return promise;
}


function initiateTable(columnArray, tableData, tab) {
//console.log("initiateTable called: " + tab);
var table = $("#table-" + tab).DataTable({
    data: tableData,
    "columns": columnArray,
    "scrollX": true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "fixedColumns": {
        leftColumns: 2
    }
});
}

var dataRetrievalpromise = function () {
var jsonData = {};
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    //console.log('first method completed ');
    resolve(jsonData = {
        "Jan-2019": {
            "metaData": {
                "month": "Jan",
                "numDays": 31,
                "year": "2019"
            },
            "data": [
                {
                    "managerName": "Person 1",
                    "employeeName": "Employee 1",
                    "Jan-01-2019": "<span style='background-color:green;'>Event 1</span>",
                    "Jan-03-2019": "Event #3"
                },
                {
                    "managerName": "Person 1",
                    "employeeName": "Employee 2",
                    "Jan-02-2019": "Event #2"
                },
                {
                    "managerName": "Person 1",
                    "employeeName": "Employee 3",
                    "Jan-01-2019": "Event #1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Feb-2019": {
            "metaData": {
                "month": "Feb",
                "numDays": 28,
                "year": "2019"
            },
            "data": [
                {
                    "managerName": "Person 1",
                    "employeeName": "Employee 1",
                    "Feb-01-2019": "<span style='background-color:green;'>Event 1</span>",
                    "Feb-03-2019": "Event #3"
                },
                {
                    "managerName": "Person 1",
                    "employeeName": "Employee 2",
                    "Feb-06-2019": "Event #2"
                },
                {
                    "managerName": "Person 1",
                    "employeeName": "Employee 3",
                    "Feb-01-2019": "Event #1"
                }
            ]
        }
    });
});
return promise;
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/fixedColumns.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div role="tabpanel">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
       <div class="tab-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap337.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/test2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine. The only thing is that following event listener of tab change is not working like as you mentioned in the comment.

```
//Below works only when debugging/using breakpoints
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true })
    .columns.adjust()
    .fixedColumns().relayout()
    .responsive.recalc();
  });
});
```

It is because you are rendering that html content dynamically and at that point of time `a[data-toggle="tab"]` element is not available. Better to place that code after you rendered the tabs and tables.

```
dataRetrievalpromise().then(function (result) {
  generateTabsPromise(result).then(function (result) {
    createTableHTMLPromise(result).then(function (result) {
      createTableColumnsAndDataPromise(result);
      $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true })
          .columns.adjust()
          .fixedColumns().relayout()
          .responsive.recalc();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://live.datatables.net/lubuxese)

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation Prashant, it worked.  Problem fixed.